# How to show number of rows on page and the total numbers of rows in report

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

In *JasperReport*'s report I have been showing data using table

In column footer I want to show total number of records per page

```
Page 1 Showing 25 records out of 65
Page 2 Showing 50 records out of 65
Page 3 Showing 15 records out of 65
```

I am using column count to show number of records per page but for total records in report what should I use

```
Page 1 Showing 25 records out of 25
Page 2 Showing 50 records out of 50
Page 3 Showing 15 records out of 65
```

Which variable should I use or any condition to be added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easy solve this task with help of  built-in variable *`$V{REPORT_COUNT}`* and custom variable.

### The working sample

#### The jrxml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="no_of_rows_on_page" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="da1c0873-1b22-4592-93a1-c9ffbdcec490">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT name FROM PRODUCT]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <variable name="rowsOnPage" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Page">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{rowsOnPage} + 1]]></variableExpression>
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="dc686db4-cb13-46c2-8420-e9ba198116e3" x="0" y="0" width="185" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="20">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="0940bce6-118f-47bc-81f6-ae03ca55ddcb" x="205" y="0" width="112" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Showing " + $V{rowsOnPage} + " records out of "]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement uuid="b5f1da29-7ac8-40a9-889e-e306a0cd26fe" x="317" y="0" width="60" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="2"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="fb9ca24d-844e-4921-8a79-85c2ec2d2888" x="159" y="0" width="46" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

#### The result

The output result generated in *iReport* via preview mode

[image: Page 2]

[image: Last page]

#### How it works

I've add 3 *textFields* on *Page Footer* band:

- 1st one is for showing current page number. The expression is: *`"Page " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}`* and the *Evaluation Time* is **Now**
- 2nd one is for showing count of rows on current page. The expression is: *`"Showing " + $V{rowsOnPage} + " records out of "'* and the *Evaluation Time* is **Now**
- 3rd one is for showing total rows in whole report. The expression is: *`$V{REPORT_COUNT}`* and the *Evaluation Time* is **Report**.

As you can see I've add custom variable *rowsOnPage* for counting number of rows on page.

The variable definition:

- ***Expression***: **`$V{rowsOnPage} + 1`**
- ***Type***: **Integer**
- ***Initial value***: **0**
- ***Reset type***: **Page**

---

See details about:
[Variables](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRVariable.html)
[Built-in variables in JasperReports Ultimate Guide](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/JasperReports-Ultimate-Guide-3.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

The variable "$V{REPORT_COUNT}" can solve your problem, use it at the evaluation time "report".

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Ireport designing tool, then u can show total very easily by placing Page X of Y from palette.

Ireport 5.5 has palette under Window menu.

Comment: I am asking how should I show total 65 65 65 instaed of 25 50 65